# auto select dropdown list with javascript and run jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, autocomplete

in html page we have 2 dropdon list when we cose somthing from first jquery work and show more option for next dropdown list, this is a html code :

```
            <select name="cat_level1" id="cat_level1" size="1" class="form-control input-inline">
                <option value="0">1</option>
                <option value="8">2</option>
                <option value="6">3</option>    
            </select>
            <select name="cat_level2" id="cat_level2" size="1" class="form-control input-inline">
                <option value="0">-</option>
            </select>

            <script>
            $("#cat_level2").chained("#cat_level1");
            </script>
```

now i try to select dropdownlist option programmatically from my win app with javascript, i use from this code for select :

```
        var len = element.options.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (element.options[i].value == selected_val)
            {
                element.options[i].selected = true;
                break; ;
            }
        }
```

thats work but with that code jquery not work and we dont get any option in secend dropdownlist .
how to select option for run that jquery after select ?

Comment: How is this related to `c#` ?

Comment: Look at [link](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/97/cascading-dropdownlists-with-jquery-and-asp-net)

Comment: i use from that javascript code in awesomium browser in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the option is selected through code the event is not fired, this is probably the reason that second select is not updated.

You would get error on `int` use `var`. Fire change event through code as well using `element.dispatchEvent`.

```
var len = element.options.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
     if (element.options[i].value == selected_val)
     {
         element.options[i].selected = true;
         var event = new Event('change');
         element.dispatchEvent(event);
         break; ;
     }
}
```

You need to call chained function from change event handler as well.

```
$("#cat_level1").on("change", function(){
   $("#cat_level2").chained("#cat_level1");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i try with your code but again i don't get any option !

Comment: Have you subscribe the change event? Do you call the chained function from change event handler?, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this?

```
$('yourSelect').find('option[value='+selected_val+']').attr('selected', true);
```

Edit: Without jQuery

```
    var len = element.options.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (element.options[i].value == selected_val)
        {
            //element.options[i].selected = true;
            element.options[i].setAttribute('value',true);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i can't execute jquery in windows app, i can use only from javascript code